# Error 'Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another'

Tags: delphi

I have been stuck with this error after trying everything i have learned.
I have two DBGrids on my form and they both have different names and are connected to two different ADO connections. When I filter the database I get the error as stated in the title, I have no idea what to do, this is how that part of my program looks.

```
procedure TfrmDatabase.btnYouTubeSearchClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  sName: string;
begin
  sName := InputBox('Enter the name of the YouTuber you want to search',
    'Please enter name here', '');
   with DataModule3 do
   begin
      tblYouTube.Open;
      tblYouTube.Filtered := false;
      tblYouTube.Filter := 'Name of YouTuber = ' + QuotedStr(sName);
      tblYouTube.Filtered := true;

   end;
end;
```

Comment: *Name of YouTuber* is three words, not a column name. As you would in a SQL statement, you need to escape those spaces using `[]` around the column name.

Comment: I googled a little, searching for that text, and found [this on the Microsoft docs site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/data/ado-error-reference?view=sql-server-2017). In other words, this is ADO error 3001, not a Delphi error.

Answer (score 2):

When using dbGO ADO connections field names with spaces need to be surrounded by brackets. It also needs to be the field name for the table and not the field title / caption so double check that.

```
  tblYouTube.Filter := '[Name of YouTuber] = ' + QuotedStr(sName);
```

From the help:  [Data.Win.ADODB.TCustomADODataSet.Filter](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/Data.Win.ADODB.TCustomADODataSet.Filter)

> When a field name contains spaces, you must enclose the field name in
>   brackets. For example:
>
> `[Home State] = 'CA' or [Home State] = 'MA'`